# Decidability of a first-order theory of hyperreals

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, decidability, nonstandard-analysis, ordered-fields

The theory of real closed fields is decidable. The [hyperreals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number) satisfy that theory, so we can interpret statements in the theory of real closed fields as being about hyperreals.

If we add a unary predicate for "is a standard real number" to the language, is the theory still decidable?

Comment: Any reason for the anonymous downvote?

Comment: Do you mean adding a predicate "standard real"? Because the predicate "is a real number" in the theory of real-closed fields would, in principle, be interpreted as "everything".

Comment: @AsafKaragila standard real, yes.

Comment: What happens if you take an ultrapower of *that* structure, then your "new" hyperreals will have the standard reals predicate cover the "old" hyperreals.

Comment: Hmm....I don't see any good way to eliminate the quantifier in $(\exists r)(Std(r) \ \wedge \ x < r < y)$.

Comment: @MattF. That would be equivalent to $y-x$ is a positive infinitesimal. Is there a way to express being an infinitesimal without quantifiers?

Comment: @PyRulez, I don't think that's equivalent to my formula -- suppose $x$ is a positive infinitesimal and $y=2x$. But if you have both division and my proposed expansion, you can express that $y-x$ is a positive infinitesimal by saying that $1/(y-x)$ is not smaller than a standard real.

Comment: @MattF. sorry, meant that $y-x$ is positive and *not* infinitesimal. And how do you express division without quantifiers.

Comment: @PyRulez, I was thinking that this language for real-closed fields would include division. To say that $y-x$ is positive and not infinitesimal, you say that $y-x>0$ and $1/(y-x)$ is less than a standard real. But I think we should stop with the comments there.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3848230/49592)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, the theory is decidable.

If $F$ is an ordered field and $R\subseteq F$ a non-cofinal subfield, then
$$O=\{x\in F:\exists u\in R\:(-u\le x\le u)\}$$
is a convex valuation ring of $F$, with maximal ideal
$$I=\{x\in F:\forall u\in R_{>0}\:(-u\le x\le u)\}.$$
$R$ embeds as a cofinal subfield in the residue field $O/I$; in general, the embedding may be proper, but if $R=\mathbb R$, then $R=O/I$, as $\mathbb R$ is complete.

Thus, let $T$ be the theory of structures $(F,R,+,\cdot,<)$ such that

1. $F$ is a real-closed field,
2. $R$ is a non-cofinal subfield of $F$, and
3. the canonical embedding of $R$ into the residue field $O/I$ as defined above is surjective (and therefore an isomorphism).

Then $T$ is a recursively axiomatized theory, it is valid in the hyperreal structures $({}^*\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$, and it is complete (see below), hence it is decidable, and axiomatizes the first-order theory of $({}^*\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$.

As pointed out in a comment by Erik Walsberg (thanks!), the completeness of $T$ is a special case of a more general result on tame elementary extensions of o-minimal structures due to Van den Dries and Lewenberg [1]. (Here, tameness is basically the axiom 3 above.) Their results also show that $T$ is model-complete, and in fact, that it has quantifier elimination in a language expanded with function symbols for roots of polynomials (which make the theory of real-closed fields universally axiomatized) and for the “standard part” map $\mathrm{st}\colon O\to R$ such that $x-\mathrm{st}(x)\in I$.

Let me indicate how to prove a weaker result: the theory $T_0$ of structures $(F,O)$ such that

1. $F$ is a real-closed field,
2. $O$ is a proper convex subring of $F$,

is complete and decidable. This follows from the Ax–Kochen–Ershov principle, which states that two henselian valued fields of residue characteristic $0$ with elementarily equivalent residue fields and value groups are elementarily equivalent.

First, it is an easy consequence of basic facts about valued fields that if $F$ is a real-closed field with a convex valuation ring $O$, then the valued field $(F,O)$ is henselian, the residue field $O/I$ is real-closed, and the value group $F^\times/O^\times$ is divisible.

Thus, if $(F,O)$ and $(F',O')$ are two models of $T_0$, their residue fields are elementarily equivalent by completeness of the theory of real-closed fields, and their value groups are elementarily equivalent by completeness of the theory of divisible totally ordered abelian groups, hence the valued fields $(F,O)$ and $(F',O')$ are elementarily equivalent by the AKE principle.

As shown by Cherlin and Dickman [2], $T_0$ has quantifier elimination in the language of ordered rings expanded with the predicate
$$x\mid y\iff y\in xO.$$

**References:**

[1] Lou van den Dries, Adam H. Lewenberg: *$T$-convexity and tame extensions*, Journal of Symbolic Logic 60 (1995), no. 1, pp. 74–102, doi: [10.2307/2275510](https://doi.org/10.2307/2275510). On [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2275510).

[2] Gregory Cherlin, Max A. Dickmann: *Real closed rings II. Model theory*, Annals of Pure and Applied Logic 25 (1983), no. 3, pp. 213–231, doi: [10.1016/0168-0072(83)90019-2](https://doi.org/10.1016/0168-0072(83)90019-2).

Comment: This also makes a good answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108951/applications-of-the-ax-kochen-ershov-ake-princicple, where I see that you cite https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Model_theory_of_valued_fields as a good resource for the Ax-Kochen-Ershov principle.

Comment: Neat! You wouldn't happen to know if quantifier elimination would work, like Matt F. speculated in a comment under the question?

Comment: The language of real closed fields has the $>$ relation. The language that the Ax–Kochen–Ershov principle talks about wouldn't have that, right?

Comment: I think it is worth pointing out that completeness of this theory is a special case of the work of van den Dries and Lewenberg on tame pairs. They also get a quantifier elimination in a reasonable language. Their results cover the analogous structure when one replaces the field of real numbers by some o-minimal expansion of the field of real numbers. https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jsl/1183744679

Comment: @ErikWalsberg Excelent, thank you. I will look at it when I get to the office.

Comment: For $T$, (3) is just saying that every hyperreal that is bounded by reals is infinitesimally close to a real, right?

Comment: Yes. ~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 1):

Here are some comments on quantifier elimination for this theory, focusing on what expansion of the language might make it work. This may be parallel to identifying a model companion, or determining the structures to consider in a more model-theoretic proof, as Emil Jerabek was proposing.

First, we will need a symbol for **having a standard real in between**, $SBet(x,y)$, to eliminate the quantifier in
$$(\exists s)(Std(s)\ \&\ x \le s \le y)$$
We can express many things in terms of this symbol, e.g.

- $x$ is standard iff $SBet(x,x)$;
- $x$ is less than some standard real iff $x<0 \vee SBet(x,x+1)$;
- $x$ is in Emil's ideal $O$ iff $x$ and $-x$ are each less than some standard real

Second, we will need symbols for **algebraic functions**. We need to be able to say that $\sqrt{x}-y$ is standard, i.e. a quantifier elimination for expressions like
$$(\exists r)(Std(r)\ \&\ (r+y)^2 = x)$$

- One obvious elimination does not work, e.g. if $x=(y+1)^2$ and $y$ is non-standardly large, then $\sqrt{x}-y$ is standard but $x-y^2$ is non-standard.
- Identifying algebraic functions by bracketing roots in rational intervals also will not work, since we will need roots that are not in rational intervals.
- We can instead use the [sign representation](https://cs.nyu.edu/mishra/PUBLICATIONS/90.p120-mishra.pdf), specifying the signs of the derivatives of the polynomial. So we add a function $a_d$ of $2d+1$ variables for each degree $d$, where we interpret, e.g. $a_2(c_0, c_1, c_2; d_1, d_2)$ as "the root of $c_0 + c_1 x + c_2 x^2$ for which $(c_0 + c_1 x + c_2 x^2)'$ has the same sign as $d_1$ and $(c_0 + c_1 x + c_2 x^2)''$ has the same sign as $d_2$, or $0$ if that description does not specify a unique $x$."

Even these additions don't make the quantifier elimination obvious. How can we eliminate the quantifier over $r$ in
$$(\exists r)(SBet(r + x,\ r + 2x)\ \&\ y < r < z)\ \text{ or}$$
$$(\exists r)(SBet(r^3 - r + x,\ r^3 - r + 2x)\ \&\ y < r < z)\ ?$$

Comment: What's the convention on how to handle values of the algebraic function that are undefined (like 1/0 or sqrt (-1)).

Comment: The convention I proposed is a value of "0 when that description does not specify a unique $x$."

Comment: Okay, sure. Do you know how to eliminate the quantifier in $(\exists s)(Std(s)\ \&\ x \lt s \lt y)$? If so, I think I have a solution for your first formula.

Comment: In my proposed language, that is equivalent to $SBet(x,y) \ \& \ (Std(x) \rightarrow SBet(x,(x+y)/2)) \ \& \ (Std(y) \rightarrow SBet((x+y)/2,y)$

Comment: Okay, let's say that the formula I commented above is called SEBet(x, y). Then the first unsolved formula in your question is equivalent to "y < z and SEBet(y+x, z+2x)".

Comment: That expression would need cases for $x\le 0$ and $x\ge 0$, so even eliminating the quantifier in the shorter expression is not trivial. The more serious issue is with the more complicated expression.